# How do I get the intellisense in FoxPro 8 to work with .net COM objects?

Tags: c#, com, interop, intellisense, visual-foxpro

I'm at my wit's end with this.  What I'm doing is making a C# dll file that needs to have some methods exposed to FoxPro 8. This guy here http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/VfpDotNetInterop/DotNetFromVFP.asp says that you can put [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] in front of the (C# in my case) class, and then intellisense in Foxpro magically works. I'm accessing the COM object fine in FoxPro, but unfortunately the intellisense doesn't work, and it's annoying me. Is there some other step I'm missing to this? Is there some registry entry to look for to confirm that the methods are exposed properly (for intellisense to work)? Are there other steps in Foxpro that I'm supposed to follow (I don't know a thing about FoxPro!)

It might be a pretty obscure question these days, but someone on here must know the answer!

Thanks

Comment: Is youre concern more of just exposing the methods to C# vs having intellisense within VFP?  Are you able to get your C# dll working otherwise?

Comment: Yeah it works, otherwise.. the methods also appear in the object viewer. Furthermore my coworker managed to get it to work somehow but we can't figure out what he did differently. *shrug*

Comment: i mean he got the full intellisense to work.

Answer (score 1):

Without my digging into some old code on another machine, I know that if you are in C# and do a

/// (triple forward slash comment)

above a method, it puts stuff like...

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
```

as header comments to your code.  That may be the thing you are missing.  It may be that the intellisense is looking to these "comment/summary" heading elements to have in the type library signatures.

Nope... no impact... got home and checked my machine / sample code... not it...